# Unable to load json File for highcharts

Tags: json, highcharts

I am trying to use highcharts to add a graph to my site.  However, I am a newby to json and I am having trouble loading the file.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/czNn2/9/

'graph-data-array2.json' contains:

```
[{
name: 'Asia',
data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
}, {
name: 'Africa',
data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
}, {
name: 'Europe',
data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
}, {
name: 'America',
data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
}, {
name: 'Oceania',
data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
}]
```

When I run this on my site there are no errors on the console and the area where the graph should be is blank. I am following the advice from the 2nd answer to this prior question: [Creating 100% stacked area graph for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331897/creating-100-stacked-area-graph-for-a-website)

I also tried a json file formated as:

```
[
["Price", "Us", "You"],
[0,0.5,0.5],
[1,0.5,0.5],
[2,0.5,0.5]
]
```

But it did not work either.  In this case I get an error in the console "Uncaught Highcharts error #13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure (since I didn't see it in your code), add your chart to your `<div id="container-chart" />`.

You can do this via adding a property to the chart options:

```
chart: {
        renderTo: container-chart,
        height: 400
    },
```

SOURCE: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo

OR use jQuery:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
```

EDIT: Turns out you can't use a hypen in the id of the div you're rendering to. Your json seems fine. Here is an updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czNn2/5

Comment: Hi Sri - Yes, I have the line '<div id="container-chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>' in my html to add the chart.  I just added 'renderTo: 'container-chart'' to the chart option but it is still not working...

Comment: I meant where is your reference to the div within the chart object?

So, I added your json to a variable and read the console log. It turns out you cannot use a hypen (-) in your div id with the highcharts "renderTo" property. Took it out and it worked. Here's the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/czNn2/5/

Comment: just tried it again, but when I try to load the data via json the graph is not showing up: http://jsfiddle.net/czNn2/9/

Comment: Now, you are trying to load the data from another domain. Take a look at your console log. Like Sebastian said, it's a cross-domain problem and your JSON needs to be wrapped by using JSONP.

CONSOLE LOG: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.locketechnologies.com/graph-data-array2.json. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with cross domain problem, because you try to load json with other domain. Solution can be usuing JSONP.